# How to get product images which are associate with its sku?

Tags: magento2, admin, image, sku

I want to upload a csv file which contains product sku and i want to get product images which are associated with that sku.please help me out.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want get image product by sku, you could try this way :

first create the custom extension folder `Company/Module` in your `<magento_root_folder>/app/code`, so the path will be `<magento_root_folder>/app/code/Company/Module`

then create `registration.php` inside `Module` folder, add this code to `registration.php` file

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

next steps create folder `etc` on inside `Module` folder, the path will to be like this : `<magento_root_folder>/app/code/Company/Module/etc`, inside `etc` folder create file `module.xml` add this code in `module.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

add again folder `frontend` in `etc` folder and create again file `routes.xml`, so the path now will be `<magento_root_folder>/app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml` with this code inside `routes.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="image" id="image">
            <module name="Company_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

now create `Controller` folder inside `Module` folder and create again `index` folder inside `Controller` folder, so the path will to be like this : `<magento_root_folder>/app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index`
create new class file inside `index` folder with `Index.php` and add this code into `Index.php` (the path now will be `<magento_root_folder>/app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php`)

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


 public function execute()
 {
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
 }

}
```

create again file `Upload.php` inside `../Controller/Index` folder and then add this code to file

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

class Upload extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $file =  fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
        $header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row

        $required_data_fields = 3;

        while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 3000, ",") ) {

            $data_count = count($row);
            if ($data_count < 1) {
                continue;
            }

            $data = array();
            $data = array_combine($header, $row);
            echo $this->getImagePathFromSku($data['sku'])."<br />";

        }

    }

    public function getImagePathFromSku($sku)
    {
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

        if($product) {
            $mediaurl= $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $imagepath = $mediaurl.'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
            return 'sku : '.$sku.' - image : <img widht="150" height="150" src='.$imagepath.' />';
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

next step create `Block\Index` folder inside `Module` folder, and add class file `Index.php` (the path should be like this : `<magento_root_folder>/app/code/Company/Module/Block/Index/Index.php`) and add this code inside `Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function postUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/Index/upload');
    }
}
```

create form for upload csv file, create folder 'view/frontend' inside `etc` folder, then create `layout` and `templates\index` folders the path will to be like these :  `<magento_root_folder>/app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout`
and `<magento_root_folder>/app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/templates\index`.
create layout file `image_index_index.xml` inside `.../view/frontend/layout`, add this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\Index\Index" name="index.index" template="Company_Module::index/index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

add again `index.phtml` inside `../view/frontend/templates/index/` folder insert with this html code :

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->postUrl(); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

open your cli and go to your magento project root and execute this command

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

next this command

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

now you can call the script with this url in your browser

`http://<your_host>/<your_magento2_folder_site>/image`

based your comment it should be :

`http://localhost/magento2/image`

it will show input file form, you can upload your csv file, I assume your csv format is to be like this :

```
"sku","name","description","short_description","price","qty"
"test-sku1","Test product name1","Test product description1","Test product short description1","100","20"
"test-sku2","Test product name2","Test product description2","Test product short description2","10","30"
```

then it will show the image path if the sku product already exist and have image.

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @mrfizh i want to get images on my localhost for testing purpose.i want to run the script as www://localhost/magento2/getimages.php

Comment: hi @charan, see my update answer.

Comment: Hi@mrfizh.This is ok.but my actual requirement is i want to upload product skus through a csv file and i want to get the product images for those uploaded skus.so i want to run the custom script as www://localhost/magento2/getimages.php.

Comment: it's okay, you can see my update answer again. hope it will helps

Comment: Hi@mrfizh It is working fine.but it is displaying like this 24-MB01 : /m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg(SKU and image name).but i want to display the image.pls suggest me the possible solution.

Comment: so you want to display image, please see my update answer for the `Upload.php` file, just replace old code with new one. After save the latest code, don't forget to execute `php bin/magento cache:clean` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` before you tried to submit again.

Comment: Hi@mrfizh. I am getting Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento225\app\code\Company\Module\Controller\Index\Upload.php on line 3 after updated the upload.php. i run both clean and upgrade commands also.

Comment: have you executed `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` in command line before ?, since there is addition constructor in the controller file you need execute this command.

Comment: Hi@mrfizh I ran again php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento cache:clean.but getting the same error after click on submit button

Comment: ah I'm sorry,  please remove line space between `<? php`  and `namespace... ` on Upload. php and make sure tag `<?php` on the top of line coding..  see again my update answer for Upload.php

Comment: Hi@mrfizh. It is working fine.Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi@mrfizh. If i want to display the output in a tabular form.how can i make changes in upload.php file. and i don't want sku: and image:.i directly want sku and image in the table.

Comment: you can make a new question for that...it better to make one question focused to one thing..  I will try to answer again your question

Comment: Hi@mrfizh I posted a new question.This is the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245167/how-to-get-product-images-based-on-its-sku.pls suggest me the possible solution.

Comment: okay, don't forget click checklist to the answer, to mark as acceptance answer that solve you problem ;)

Comment: Hi@mrfizh I accepted your answer by click on the check list.pls suggest me the possible solution to display the sku and image in a tabular form.

Comment: Hi @charan, could you come to this chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84079/magento-room

Comment: Hi@mrfizh.I am unable to chat in the chat room. it is saying you must have 20 reputations to chat.i want to display sku and image in the tabular form.

Comment: ah I see let me comment on your question :)

Comment: as this question still not get acceptance answer, are you sure have click checklist on this answer like this screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/XZsmFgr

Comment: Hi@mrfizh.pls check now.

Comment: thanks it will help other if have same problem with you ;)

Comment: Hi@mrfizh Pls suggest me the possible solution to display the output in a tabular form with sku and image.

Comment: okay let me try first in my local pc, once I got tested and make sure the correct answer I will post on the answer..